【Flutter】How to set the background image of the entire application

My attempt:
I have tried add a Stack Widget to my application root node.But when I use Get.toNamed navigation from the homePage to another page,The Widget which I has add to the application root node has invisible.
The Image source which was added to application root node is dynamic，Actually, is a watermarked image，and the text on the watermark only changes with the user's online status..
I don't know if my idea or approach is correct。
The code below:


Expected:

The WaterMark Images can serve as the background for the entire app。
Or

How to achieve the effect 。
I need your help,thanks.



When you use Get.toNamed what you essentially do is add a route onto the MaterialApp. So if you need the HomePage (assuming it has your image in question) to be visible on all routes you will have to change your routing logic or add `HomePage to all routes. First one is preferred due to redundancy and optimisation. But really depends on your use case.
